# The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in MySQL8.20

Tags: mysql, linux

My knowledge in MySQL is very simple.

I installed MySQL 8.20 and as [here](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-4-new-default-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password/) to say, the Authentication Plugin was changed.
I tried as [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html) to say,

logged in to MySQL:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

wrote:

> CREATE USER 'sha2user'@'localhost'
>
> IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';

In my file /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf I wrote:

> default_authentication_plugin=caching_sha2_password

and restarted MySQL:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysq
```

Then on my **Adminer** I wrote **user: root** and **Password: my new password**, but got this warning:

> The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Can someone please help me?

Comment: try also allowing 127.0.0.1 or specify your host as localhost when you try to login

Comment: Try updating Adminer as well.

Comment: @ I doing as your to say and to come same warning.. @Milan Velebit I tried Adminer to update but because I'm with **debian** it not update it..

Comment: @Milan Velebit  I deleted on my debian the old Adminer, donwnload and the install  the new version 4.7.7, but come the same warming **The server requested authentication method unknown to the client**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, found the solution...

My problem was how had installed ALL...
I removed ALL of Mysql on my Debian, I to search what i have of Mysql and MariaDB with `dpkg -l | grep -e mysql -e mariadb`, than with **Synaptic** delete ALL then..
Than Folge all as [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/install-adminer-database-management-tool-on-debian-10/#comments) to say.. Now have the last Adminer, 4.7.7 and all working gut..